# MySQL Query to take Stock data from one table and update LIKE data on a second table

Tags: php, mysql

Ok lets see if I can put this in words. I have 2 tables, with like data. They are meant to serve as Stock data for the rest of the system to use. One of the tables is a recent addition, and 2 columns worth of data on said table need to match the data on the other tables so I can attempt to make faster running queries. That said. The columns I need to fix have very similar data to that of the one I want it to be like. As in I could do a select query from the second table onto the first one using `like` and actually get the data I want, but I can't do that in reverse.

So Heres what I want to know if its even possible just doing it query based. Essentially I want to run over the second table that I want 2 columns of data to match that of the one in the first table. They are varchar columns, as whats in them are just strings. But using sports I guess as an example in the first table I have:

New York Giants

New England Patriots

in the Second table I have:

Patriots

Giants

And while this query is going on I want to update the rows in the second column to match the data in the first table. Is this possible just query based alone or is this something I have to come up with some level of server side logic to over come?

In one table I am working with about 4000 rows in the other I am working with 1001, not sure if that helps any but worth mentioning.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you want to do? I can imagine that this not only depends on the actual table structures (missing in your question) but also on the data therein (partially given in your question). I think it's better you give a more concrete example what you want to achieve, e.g. the state in form of two tables and the result in form of a table.

Comment: Lets pretend I have the 2 tables, one is a single column of just strings, that are names, all the other tables in the DB use these strings as a base, to avoid variations from user based inputs.. the other table has 2 columns, where it has a partial version of the strings from the first table, I want to take those columns and match them to the column on the table. So they are all the same string respectfully so I can avoid `LIKE` based queries in the long run

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how you can actually obtain the existing data in a form that is suitable for the question. Consider it as extra service. However it's not an answer, just a lengthy comment.

Comment: Also you want to normalize your data and replace all "the same string meaning the same" strings with actual numeric IDs related to a table that connects these base-names to just a unique number. You can then equally link the long names to that table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into your database with the mysql commandline client and select the database. Then type in something like:

```
mysql> describe config;
```

Which will output the definition of the table *config*. Copy it and add it to your question:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Do that for your two tables.

Then also get some exemplary data for these tables, like:

```
mysql> select * from config LIMIT 5;
```

Which you then can copy and paste again:

```
+----+---------------------------+
| id | option                    |
+----+---------------------------+
|  1 | value for option with ID1 |
|  2 | value for option with ID2 |
+----+---------------------------+
```

That should make it more concrete what you are asking about, at least the existing data. Then try to formulate the outcome you would like to achieve, best with a similar layout.